org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException in Apache Came 4.x.x
I have an application with Spring Boot and Apache Camel. With camel 3.x.x, posting a file as multipart/file-data worked well. However, post upgrading the camel to 4.x.x is not working with the below exception.

org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has type: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity on: Message. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity to the required type: java.io.InputStream. Exchange[4b9a80b2-4df5-4c34-8563-33d112735881]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity to the required type: java.io.InputStream]
at org.apache.camel.support.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:128)
at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.createRequestEntity(HttpProducer.java:776)
at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.createMethod(HttpProducer.java:665)
...
...
...
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity to the required type: java.io.InputStream

Can anyone please help with this issue? Exact camel version is 4.5.0

Can you show your route builder code? The error seems clear, as you're getting a body of type MultipartFormEntity which you actually expect, but somehow you're treating it or part of your logic is expecting an InputStream for further processing.
